# Nested object destructuring with redux and react

Tags: redux, object-destructuring

I'm following a tutorial in React Redux. I have created a store variable with Redux store which has two sub variables. One is `expenses` which is an array of objects and another is `filters` which is an object itself.

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        expenses: expensesReducer,
        filters: filtersReducer
    })
);
```

When filled with dummy values the store would look like this:

```
const dummyState = {
    expenses: [{
        id: '10-AC-191',
        title: 'January Rent',
        note: 'This was the final payment for that address',
        amount: 545.00,
        createdAt: 0
    }, {
        id: '10-AK-155',
        title: 'Breakfast',
        amount: 545.00,
        createdAt: 2000
    }],
    filters: {
        text: 'rent',
        sortBy: 'amount',
        startDate: 700,
        endDate: 360,
    }
};
```

I'm currently writing a function to display resultant expenses array which looks like this.

```
const getVisibleExpenses = (expenses, {text, sortBy, startDate, endDate}) => {
    return expenses.filter(({title, note, createdAt}) => {
        const startDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || createdAt >= startDate;
        const endDateMatch = typeof endDate !== 'number' || createdAt <= endDate;

        const searchText = text.trim().toLowerCase();
        const textMatch = typeof text !== 'string' || title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
            || note.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);

        return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch;
    }).sort((expense_a, expense_b) => {
        if (sortBy === 'amount') return expense_a.amount - expense_b.amount;
        else if (sortBy === 'date') return expense_a.createdAt - expense_b.createdAt;
    });
};
```

This function takes `store.expenses`, `store.filters` as two inputs. So I wanted to pass in `store` object only and get the output.

Hence I tried to object destructure the input store itself instead of calling store below. But it returns an error.

```
const getVisibleExpenses = ({expenses, {text, sortBy, startDate, endDate}})
```

Is there any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const getVisibleExpenses = ({expenses, filters: {text, sortBy, startDate, endDate}}) => {}
```